# Add theme options to custom post type admin pages

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I have custom post types set up using CCTM plugin and I'm using the Bridge Theme by Qode.

The theme adds options to the posts and pages admin (custom theme options, title area, header etc.), I'm trying get the same options for the CCTM pages in the admin.

I've been through the functions.php for the theme but can't seem to figure out where it's being added to the posts/pages admin.

If any WP gurus could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. I can provide any further info if needed.

Comment: It's poor development by the theme developers to hard-code the post types. Now you're forced to hack the theme or copy multiple files to a child theme. Disappointing

Answer (score 2):

Theme uses custom meta boxes. If you go this path,

```
/wp-content/themes/bridge/framework/admin/meta-boxes
```

you will find folders. There is a `map.php` file in this folders. You can duplicate this folders and rename if you want to use for your CPT's.

Theme uses own metabox class `QodeMetaBox` when you duplicate files you need to change this code (for ex. i use SEO metabox);

```
$qodeSeo = new QodeMetaBox("page", "Qode SEO");
$qodeFramework->qodeMetaBoxes->addMetaBox("page_seo",$qodeSeo);
```

to:

```
$qodeSeo = new QodeMetaBox("post_type", "Qode SEO");
$qodeFramework->qodeMetaBoxes->addMetaBox("post_type_seo",$qodeSeo);
```

Where `post_type` is the string used as first parameter in `register_post_type()`, and `post_type_seo` is an unique string.

after that you need to include/call your new map file `into qode-meta-boxes-setup.php` after    `require_once("carousels/map.php");`;

```
require_once("your-new-folder-name/map.php");
```

In addition to the above, the `post_type` needs to be added in the `qode_meta_box_save` function, so that the values will actually be saved to the database. Change framework\qode-framework.php on line 340:

```
$postTypes = array( "page", "post", "portfolio_page", "testimonials", "slides", "carousels");
```

to:

```
$postTypes = array( "page", "post", "portfolio_page", "testimonials", "slides", "carousels", "post_type");
```

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your answer. 

This works nicely except there are 5 different page types and it only seems to add the last require_once in the list in the qode-meta-boxes-setup.php. I've created each folder and updated the files appropriately. If I rearrange the list, it only works for the last one. Any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: Interesting, if you change files properly script should work. Every post types has own folder and you create `map.php` files for each post types. 

When you add your own file as require_once, other post types (post,page,slider etc.) also had metaboxes, right?

Comment: Yeah, I've created 5 folders (audio, music, film, game, animation) with the map.php copied from page/map.php and all instances of "new QodeMetaBox("page".." changed to the appropriate page type ("audio", "music" etc.).

All the Qode options are available in both posts & pages when there are no extra "required_once" but not available in pages when there are any extras added. Seems like there's a conflict in map.php? I can't see anything obvious though.. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Probably you forget some changes in map.php files. If you add properly fore example
`require_once("audio/map.php");require_once("video/map.php");`
Script should work for each post type. please double check the map.php files.

Comment: I've double & triple checked the map.php files. As long as the only things to change are the QodeMetaBox("post-type".. Then they are all correct. And they are added as you say, require_once("audio/map.php");require_once("video/map.php"); etc. it seems like the variables are being overwritten by each require but I would have thought the scope would be restricted to each file? It's very frustrating! Besides changing all the variables in each map.php, I can't think of anything else to do.